# No puedo insertar valores en la base de datos con Java Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

tengo una base de datos y quiero que inserte valores en la tabla ... el programa no arroja ningún error ... pero simple no inserta los valores en la base de datos ... Cuando hago una inserción a través de la base de datos está bien ... pero puedo a través del servlet ...

¿Cuál es el problema? He puesto la biblioteca JDBC. Estoy usando el servidor GlasshFish.

```
 package hotelreserva;


 import java.util.*;  
 import java.sql.*; 
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;










      public class cliente {




      private static Connection getConnection() {
      //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | 
      Templates.
     try {


     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     Connection con= cliente.getConnection(); 
     DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotelres", "root", "root");
     PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into 
     T_reserva (localizador) values (?)");  


    cliente c;
    c = new cliente();
    ps.setString(1,"sdsdsd");  

    ps.executeUpdate();



   } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();

  }
  return null;
```

Comment: puedes compartir tu log ? completa por favor la función, te faltan los corchetes de cierre del método estático y de la clase

Comment: `ant -f /home/educacion/NetBeansProjects/hotelres -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=/home/educacion/NetBeansProjects/hotelres run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Undeploying ...
In-place deployment at /home/educacion/NetBeansProjects/hotelres/build/web
run-deploy:
Browsing: http://localhost:8080/hotelres
run-display-browser:
run:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno hay un par de cosas que me llaman la atención, primero la tabla mysql que empiece con mayúscula, habitualmente empiezan con minusculas, luego que hablas de servlet pero no veo ni doGet() ni doPost(). No sé tu nivel de programación relacionada a servlets pero te voy a dar un ejemplo íntegro de cómo deberías hacer eso que estabas tratando de hacer. Primero crear un dynamic web proyect, segundo que el sistema te cree dentro de la carpeta WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml es excluyente para que funcionen los servlets clásicos.

Ahora te voy a pasar una lista de pasos a tener en cuenta:

**Archivo de conexión:**

```
package com.soa.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionStackOverflow {

private final static String user = "root";
private final static String password = "root";

public static Connection getConexion() throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotelres" , user, password);
    return connection;
}

public static void closeConnection() throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    getConexion().close();
}
}
```

**Archivo de Controlador de insercción a DB**

```
package com.soa.controllers;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import com.soa.dao.ConnectionStackOverflow;

public class ClientController {

public static void insertClient(String localizador) {
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = ConnectionStackOverflow.getConexion();

        if (connection != null) {
            PreparedStatement ps;
            String sql = "INSERT INTO T_reserva(localizador) VALUES(?)";
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, localizador);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
            System.out.println("Query executed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connection appears to be null");
        }
    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("Cannot even connect");
        error.getMessage();
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

**Archivo Servlet que debería estar conectado o declarado en el web.xml prestar atención**

```
package com.soa.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.soa.controllers.ClientController;

public class LocalizadorServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {

        String localizador = request.getParameter("localizador");
        ClientController.insertClient(localizador);

    } catch (Exception error) {
        error.getMessage();
        error.printStackTrace();
    }

    response.getWriter().append("Los datos fueron insertados");
}
}
```

**Archivo JSP (Dentro de WebContent, en este caso le pusimos index.jsp) con un FORM desde donde vas a enviar el dato que va a llegar al Servlet y el servlet lo va a ingresar al método de la clase ClientController**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<!-- el envío de datos lo estamos haciendo por javascript capturando los datos del form y enviándolo directamente al servlet -->
<script type="text/javascript">

function send(){
    var frm = document.frmLocalizador;
    frm.submit();
}

</script>

<body>
    <h1>Localizador</h1>

    <form action="LocalizadorServlet" method="get" name="frmLocalizador">
        <input type="text" name="localizador" />
        <input type="button" value="boton" onclick="send()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Archivo web.xml configuración con respecto a la ruta de los paquetes junto con el servlet**

```
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
        <display-name>StackOverflowWeb</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>LocalizadorServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.soa.servlets.LocalizadorServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>LocalizadorServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/LocalizadorServlet</url-pattern>

        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**Imagen de cómo debería quedar la estructura de proyecto.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No quiero parecer soberbio, pero si no te anda luego con estos archivos es porque hay algun conflicto con respecto a la ruta, usuario y/o contraseña de la conexión, como también puede ser que no está bien hecha la query de insert, porque tampoco determinaste el tipo de dato que recibe la tabla ni la cantidad total de columnas que tiene la misma. **Otro tema atener en cuenta es que el conector lo descargas de acá y lo copias a la carpeta WEB-INF/lib**, una vez ahi tocás **botón derecho sobre el archivo -> Build Path -> add to Build Path**.

**El conector lo descargas de acá:**

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6
Tenés que descargar el que dice JAR.

Otro conector puede andar también pero ése nunca me falló.

Lo probé con una tabla que creé con ése nombre de columna y funciona muy bien, sin embargo te dejé la query original en el código que hice.

Te hice un mini proyecto servlet en una hora, muchas empresas muy grandes siguen laburando con este sistema pero con cantidades interminables de servlets inmantenibles, Bueno si te sirvió marcala como solucionada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que agregaste el connector al build path, vas a poder usar los paquetes internos que tiene ése conector en tu proyecto sin embargo no te preocupes que con éso no tenés que hacer nada vos.

Si pones el conector, y estás seguro que la clave y contraseña junto con la dirección está bien configurada en el archivo de conexión y sin embargo no anda igual, podes intentar cambiando esta línea asi:

***DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/hotelres" , user, password);***

Excluyendo el número de puerto en la ruta quizás funca.

Si te sirve algo de lo que te pasé fijate de clavarle un voto o algo que me demandó bastante tiempo hacer esta respuesta y sé que funciona bien.

Axel.

Comment: @tomas espero que te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias ¡¡¡ ... seguro que me va a servir  .... ¡¡ .... cualquier consulta te escribo... Saludos..

Comment: no uso maven... hay otra alternativa.. con el diver de mysql .. me sirve ..?

Comment: No necesitas maven para nada, maven sólo es una herramienta, en la dirección que te pasé está el archivo .JAR para descargar manualmente. igualmente ahi te agrego como se hace pero en la respuesta

Comment: cuando corro el index.html me tira ...`HTTP Status 405 - El Metodo HTTP POST no es soportado por esta URL

type Status report

messageEl Metodo HTTP POST no es soportado por esta URL

descriptionThe specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1`

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action = "insertar" method = "POST">
         First Name:  <input type="text" name="localizador" />
         <br />
        
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
      </form>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: Lo solucione.. ¡¡¡¡ en el index.. tenia que poner `method=GET` y lo tenia en `POST`... ahora anda.. ¡¡¡¡

Comment: como hago para dar por solucionado la pregunta... ???

Comment: @tomas A la izquierda de mi respuesta deberia haber un icono para que puedas tocar y ponga una tilde verde, si, con respecto a al error 405, es que el método no es correcto, cuando declarás en el form  el method como "post" tiene que impactar en un doPost() y cuando declaras un "get" tiene que impactar en un doGet(). Felicitaciones!!!!